# What are the intentions of the different forms of Armature/Bone Parent/Child relationships?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, rigify

Hello to every blender user,

AFAIK I can parent a bone to a part of the mesh (in the specific case the `teeth.t` bone and the `upper_teeth_boy`) in two ways :

1) I go under the object tab and I chose `rig.boy` on the `parent` field and `teeth.T` bone under the `bone` field. But it didn't work,because the `upper_teeth_boy` takes a strange angle

2) instead,if I select the `upper_teeth_boy` first and `teeth.T` for second and then I press `CTRL P` and then `set parent to bone`,it works.

In the attached video,I have parented `upper_teeth_boy` and `teeth.T` using the procedure explained on point `2)` and then I removed the parent and I did the same but using the procedure explained on the point `1)` but it didn't work. Why ? Thanks.

[demonstration video 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vrhf_PTNauVHdPeFpMRGc0aTQ/view)

[blender file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vrhf_PTNauMXZwRXZhVnFJLVE/view?usp=sharing)

I didn't use the "Keep transform" option. This behaviour appears also if parent has default loc/rot/scale,as you can see from this video : [demonstration video 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vrhf_PTNauektITWZvUmg2TVU/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: it would be better to upload a file (at least an example file) to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/, then edit your Q and past the provided link. Because that video is temporary, and also a rigged human model is usually complex and people needs to try what is not working... also some well thought screenshot would help maybe

Comment: done. I put the video and the blender file on my google drive account and I made the folder public.

Comment: Suggestion. Please add pictures to your question and use [local view mode] for temporary visibility to focus on the primary elements of you question only. Your Video could benefit from the same. Make a selection and use numpad slash (/) to enter local mode. Your already know  Local Mode.

Comment: You may also want to show in picture the final results of the values of the Parent and Bone entries of the Relations Parent Panel.  We the readers do not know those values.  Such a panel is shown in the candidate answer below.

Comment: Your question can still improve.

Comment: I have edited the question,adding the correct video.

Answer (score 0):

**Parent Child Relationship and Keep Transform**

[image]

- There are different ways to create a Parent/Child relationship in Blender or parent.
- Keep Transform stealthily does the appropriate math with matrices to preserve child placement.
- Some ways have [immediate] effect in placement, others (Keep Transform) [delayed].

[image]

[image]

- In the two object parent and armature parent menus above we see (Keep Transform) as a valuable option.
- The [Keep Transform] genre intentionally preserve child placement at the time of parent assignment, then you move the Parent for different results.
- You should choose the one the best suits your context.  If the [immediate] effect is not what you want today, then the suggestion is to view it as a feature that you may use in the future for a positive Blender User experience.
- Both parent menus above have many different options so you may expect this as a feature.  All of those options may be useful to Blender Users in some particular cases.
- Via Control-P use Keep Transform for the case in question.  Manually filling in Parent does not necessarily [Keep Transform].  If the parent has any (non default) Scale, Rotations, or Translation the new Child will be transformed accordingly.  Expect this designed behavior.  It is a feature not a defect.
- This was intended as a short explanation.  See more here at BSE or the online Blender Manual

Comment: I didn't use the "Keep transform" option. This behaviour appears also if parent has default loc/rot/scale,as you can see from this video : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vrhf_PTNauck52MUlxSlAyWlk/view?usp=sharing

Comment: @Marietto Suggestion.  Read what is written above.  Take time to think about it.  Take a perspective of Blender Feature and Not Blender Defect.  Your understanding can improve.  Your video is not very helpful for me.  The reasons are stated in a previous comment.

Comment: excus-me,I sent you the link of the wrong video,check this : https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_vrhf_PTNauektITWZvUmg2TVU/view?usp=sharing